# Conditional CURL from Terminal

Tags: curl, terminal

I am trying to make a Curl to send a post request to a Slack webhook if the developer enters a specific terminal command. Is that possible? Is it possible to make a conditional curl command depending on the command entered?

**For example:**

If Dev X enters `deploy backend xxx..`

**The curl:**

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"text":"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}' \
 https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

..is executed in the background while the developer does their thing. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is something more related to the tool used to deploy rather than **curl**, what you could do, is to use a `Makefile`

You could use this as a start point

```
.PHONY all clean curl destroy test

all: clean

clean:
   your clean command

curl: 
    curl -X POST -H # your curl params

deploy: curl
    your deploy command

test: curl
    your test command
```

And you could use it like:

```
make deploy
```

or

```
make test
```

What basically is doing is calling curl before start to deploy or test.

Hope this can give you some ideas.

Comment: Sounds great! From what I understand, a Makefile is a set of commands grouped in to one command? Can you direct me to a guide that helps set this up please? :)

Comment: right, I can suggest some links like https://cbednarski.com/articles/makefiles-for-everyone/, https://bost.ocks.org/mike/make/ makefiles are very versatile but there are multiple ways of using them, every case is different

Comment: This definitely answered my requirements! Thank you. May I ask how I can run multiple make commands at once? Can I include `all: clean curl` and then run `make all`?

Comment: Yes, for example, check how this project is using `all: clean build` https://github.com/immortal/immortal/blob/master/Makefile#L10

Comment: This is great. Thanks for your time nbari